# What's the best 'out of the box' way to copy files to a cloud server?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, backup, cloud

I need to copy files to a newly provisioned Amazon Windows 2008 server. FTP seems to be frowned upon these days, so what is the recommended way of getting files to the machine? Ideally without installing any third-party software e.g. SSH. I've got my RDP connection sharing a local drive with the cloud server, but would also like to be able to automate file transfers for backups etc.

Answer (score 1):

IIS FTP supports FTP over SSL. It is easy to set it up and it is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Use WinRM and Powershell. It is on by default in Amazon Windows images.

There is a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635238/send-files-over-pssession)

and a more complete solution [here](http://poshcode.org/2216)